# Cosine modulated impulse response

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, modulation, bandpass, upsampling

[image]

How do we show  $y_0(n) = y_1(n)$
when $h_k[n] = h[n] \cos(\frac{2\pi}{L} k n )$

Comment: hk(n) = h0(n)cos(2pikn/L)*

Comment: Hi!. Homework? Show your work, and where you've been stuck in. Hints: You need to consider i- what happens to the signal spectrum after the expander block, ii- Fourier modulation thorem to describe Hk(z), iii- H0(x) is a lowpass filter of proper bandwidth?

Comment: H0(n) is a lowpass